# Linked list in contract storage?

Tags: solidity, evm

I'd like to implement a linked list in contract storage

Something link this:

```
contract A {

  struct LinkedList {
    uint    value;
    LinkedList storage next; // What goes here? Can I reference the storage of the next struct in solidity?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Within your struct you will want to keep track of the next item in the list

```
struct LinkedList {
    bytes32 next;
    uint value;
}
```

> Then keep track of the lenth + head of the list and store the structs in a mapping with their ID's

```
uint public length;
bytes32 public head;
mapping (bytes32 => LinkedList) public listObjects;
```

> You can add entries like this:

```
function addEntry(uint _number) public returns (bool) {
    LinkedList memory object = LinkedList(head,_number);
    bytes32 id = sha3(_number, length, block.timestamp);
    listObjects[id] = object;
    head = id;
    length++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a linked list because arrays in Solidity are automatically expanded and this would just add gas execution overhead.